# Yii2 how to set default language in codemix url manager

Tags: yii2, yii2-urlmanager

This app ru language start

```
    'language'=>'uz',
'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                '*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@frontend/messages',
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'uz',
                    'fileMap' => [
                        'main' => 'main.php',
                        'yii' => 'yii.php',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'codemix\localeurls\UrlManager',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableLanguageDetection' => true,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
//            'defaultLanguage'=>'uz',
            'enableDefaultLanguageUrlCode' => true,
            'languages' => ['uz', 'ru','oz','en'],
```

I am set system langugae uz, source langugae uz and codemix url manager one method have defaultLangugae but its not working
[this error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEhGs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Never used it but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls/blob/master/UrlManager.php#L27) it says you need to use the `languages` option as an array of language codes. More specific patterns should come first, e.g. `'en_us'` before `'en'`. This can also contain mapping of `<url_value> => <language>`, e.g. `'english' => 'en'`.

ou need to change the option to `'languages' => ['en_us'],`

Comment: I am need set default lang in array language

Comment: you must setup language for app config

Comment: @Abdualiym i think thats what i have already suggested and the last line of my answer addresses the exact thing. whats your point?

Comment: sorry, my comment was short. This is about app config param `'language' => 'en'`. So app launches if no session here with default language

Answer (score 0):

You must setup language for app config.

UPD:
Setup config(`frontend/config/main.php`) to needed language for app. Then first time app will launch in this language:
`'language' => 'en'`.

#### If this not work check in incognito mode, you must clean old session saved cookies